# Python: how can this code use negative integer 0 as a distinct index value?

Tags: python, indexing

My algorithm takes a list `[0,-0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3]` etc. and does the following in pseudocode:

```
while list:
    d = list.pop()
    objects[abs(d)] *= sign(d)
```

One can see here why it's necessary to have `-0`. My code would have to be a lot less elegant if I stored the signs seperately or indexed from 1 or something. How can I get python to store a `0` and `-0`?

EDIT:
Basically I'm implementing backtracking search. So you have the variables in that list in an arbitrary order, and the minus sign indicates setting false. It goes through and sets 0 to true, then 0 to false, then 1 to true, then -1 to false, etc. The most elegant way to do it, in my opinion, is to combine the truth value with the index by using a minus sign.

EDIT:
I found a better way to do what I'm trying to do using deques. I will leave this question up so that the answers here aren't wasted.

Comment: In C, on a two's-complement machine (almost any modern platform), setting the sign bit for integer `0` will not give you -0, it'll give you `2147483648`.

Comment: You can use `-0.0`. If your list is fixed, why don't you just count from `0` to `n` and perform both the positive and the negative cases at the same time?

Comment: More generally, C, like Python, does not have `-0` as an integer, but may have `-0` as a `float` (on IEEE float platforms, which is again almost any modern platform).

Comment: It looks like you are indexing into a separate array and going from both sides of it. Can you describe what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @abarnert: Typo: Setting the sign bit will give you *negative* 2147483648, or some bigger number if you're not using 32-bit ints.

Comment: You can store float `-0.0` but it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Abarnert, C does indeed have -0 if it uses ones' complement or sign/magnitude encodings :-) Rene, you need to describe _what_ you're trying to do rather than _how._

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, looks like I screwed up by quoting the `-`.

Comment: Give us a proper example of `list` (and don't call it list, btw). Presumably it's not guaranteed that your list has all the integers in range(n), in order, and first positive and then negative, respectively. Otherwise there would be no need for this code.

Comment: @paxdiablo: That's why I said "on a two's-complement machine (almost any modern platform)". C cannot have `-0` on such a platform. It _may_ have `-0` on other encodings, but the language doesn't require that to be treated as `-0`.

Comment: Abarnet, apologies, I was referring to the third comment, not realising it was an extension of the first.

Comment: One last thing: The `sign` functions in most other languages that have one will return `0` for both `0` and `-0`, not `1` and `-1`. That's part of the reason `copysign` exists (and part of the reason Python has `copysign`, but not `sign`).

Comment: Actually, one _more_ last thing: `objects[-0]` and `objects[0]` are going to be the same thing, while `objects[-1]` and `objects[1]` are going to be the last and second elements on `objects`, which doesn't seem very likely to be meaningful in any way.

Comment: Why is there a `-0.0` but not a `-0`? I know (now) that it's consistent with C, but why?

Comment: Trying to use the sign bit as a general-purpose flag isn't a good idea, for reasons like this, and because if it later turns out you need the sign bit to represent sign, you're screwed.

Comment: As for why there's no `-0`, it's not nearly as useful. When floating-point calculations underflow from the negative side, having a -0.0 represents useful information. There isn't any similar underflow condition for ints, and having a bit pattern reserved for -0 has awkward results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Blender use floats and the function `copysign`:

```
import math
list=[0.0,-0.0,1.0,-1.0,2.0,-2.0,3.0,-3.0]
objects={}
while list:
    d = round(list.pop(),10)
    if d not in objects:
        objects[d]=1.0
    objects[d] *= math.copysign(1.0,d)
```

Comment: You can't actually index a list with a float, though, even if the float has integral value.

Comment: @user2357112 : so coerce it: `objects[int(d)] ...`

Comment: floats can be used as keys for a dictionary but we have to normalize the keyspace using round()

Comment: `round(d, 10)` doesn't help. First, `round` still returns a float, not an int. Second, why would rounding to only 10 decimal digits make something more int-ish anyway?

Comment: @Navith: yes, but `list[-1]` probably doesn't do what the OP expects anyway, and its behavior depends on length of the list. The example is contrived. Do any of you know what the OP is really trying to do? I don't. Maybe they just need `enumerate(list_of_signs)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution that does not involve the use of float.
We can define a class which functions as `-1` when we try to get its sign and as `0` when we use it as an index into an array, using the magic methods for [emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

```
class NegativeZero:
    def __index__(self):
       return 0
    def __int__(self):
       return -1
    def __abs__(self):
       return 0

N = NegativeZero()

myList = [0,N,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3]
while myList:
    d = myList.pop()
    objects[abs(d)] *= sign(int(d))
```

Comment: The list can have arbitrary order, for example `[-1,-0,1,0,2,-2]`

Comment: @RenéG, I realize you found an alternative way, but in case you were curious, there's a way to do this with classes.

Comment: It's kind of misleading to have `__index__` and `__int__` return different values. If you try to use this value in any other context (like multiplying it by another number) it's not going to act like `-0`.

Comment: @abarnert that is very true but the op had a very specific problem.

Comment: Sure, assuming the values in this list won't be used for anything else.